# Ubuntu/Darling - dyld: Failed to load native library: libSimpleWebKit.so

Tags: linux, macos, ubuntu

I'm attempting to use [Darling](https://github.com/LubosD/darling/tree/master) directly built from source on Github, I ran in to a few issues with building and dependencies, but with the help of apt-file I got through all the little problems. Now, I'm trying to run [Sourcetree From Atlassian](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) (as Wine can't seem to handle the windows version) and am getting the following error. Would anyone happen to have an idea on why? Currently running Ubuntu 13.04 64bit.

```
dyld: Cannot execute binary file: Failed to load native library: libSimpleWebKit.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had this error myself. The error message tells you already everything you need to know: The appropriate library - `libsimplewebkit` - was not found and needs to be installed. Just search for `simplewebkit` with your distros package manager and install the appropriate package. If it doesn't find anything you will need to compile it yourself.